# Swift loop execution time is 20x slower when adding print statement that is executed once at the end

Tags: swift

My Swift app iterates over two `Array<String>` and compares their elements.

Something very strange is going on. I have the impression the compiler is doing some optimizations that I cannot understand: commenting out the print statement in `MyInterface.run()` improves the runtime from about 10 seconds to below 0.5 seconds, and that print statement is executed only once at the end of the program. Even commenting out the `if` above it has the same effect.

I'm running the app in Xcode Instruments. When debugging it in Xcode, there is no difference when commenting out any of those two lines.

Instruments shows that most of the time is spent in `protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance [A]`, `Array.subscript.read` and similar, which in turn call different `malloc`, `initialize`, `free` and `release` methods.

[image]

What's the problem with this code?

```
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let x = Array(repeating: "adsf", count: 100000)
        let y = Array(repeating: "adsf", count: 100000)
        let diff = MyInterface(x: x, y: y)
        diff.run()
    }

}

class MyInterface<List: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection> where List.Element: Comparable, List.Index == Int {
    
    private let algorithm: Algorithm<List>
    
    init(x: List, y: List) {
        algorithm = AlgorithmSubclass(x: x, y: y)
    }
    
    func run() {
        algorithm.run()
        if (0..<1).randomElement() == 0 {
            print(algorithm.x.count) // commenting out this line, or the if above, makes the program 20x faster
        }
    }
    
}

class Algorithm<List: RandomAccessCollection> where List.Element: Equatable, List.Index == Int {
    
    var x: List
    var y: List
    
    init(x: List, y: List) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
    
    func run() {
    }
    
}

class AlgorithmSubclass<List: RandomAccessCollection>: Algorithm<List> where List.Element: Equatable, List.Index == Int {
    
    override func run() {
        var count = 0
        for _ in 0..<1000 {
            for i in 0..<min(x.endIndex, y.endIndex) {
                if x[i] == y[i] {
                    count += 1
                }
            }
        }
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "\(count)"
        alert.runModal()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `-O` option and/or whole module optimisation for both cases?

Comment: I didn't change anything in the default Xcode project settings. The Build Settings for `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` have a setting `Optimization Level - Release - Optimize for Speed [-O]`, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Nickkk That's the one! And are you building/running it in Release mode?

Comment: As far as I know, building for Instruments uses Release mode.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be caused by inlining. By default, with optimizations turned on (e.g. when building for **Release**), the compiler inlines all method calls that it has access to, and which don't explicitly disable inlining (`@inline(never)`).

What happens is that when you comment out the `print(algorithm.x.count)` the compiler can aggressively inline both the initializer as well as the `run` method of `MyInterface`, resulting in a direct and concrete call to `AlgorithmSubclass.run` (i.e. no dynamic dispatch), just like `MyInterface` would not even exist (all its code is inlined).

Further more, the compiler is able to determine the exact instance for the `List` generic argument, so is able optimize the code of `AlgorithmSubclass.run`. It will no longer have to go through dynamic dispatch for the collection, nor through dynamic dispatch for the `Equatable` protocol, it can go straight to the `Array` and `String` method calls.

The inlining result in a serious performance boost, due to the huge amount of method calls that are no longer dynamically dispatched. There are 1000*100000=10^8 order of magnitude calls to the array subscript and string equatable conformances.

```swift
for _ in 0..<1000 {
    for i in 0..<min(x.endIndex, y.endIndex) { // 2 dynamic dispatches to `endIndex`
        if x[i] == y[i] { // 2 dynamic dispatches for subscript, one dynamic dispatch for `==`
            count += 1
        }
    }
} // TOTAL: 3*10^8+2*10^3 protocol witness table lookups
```

---

Try decorating either `MyInterface.init` or `MyInterface.run` with `@inline(never)` and you'll see that the execution duration stays the same, with or without the `print` statement.

```swift
class MyInterface<List: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection> where List.Element: Comparable, List.Index == Int {
    // ...
    @inline(never)
    func run() {
    // ...
}
```

Or, try the other way around, remove all generic constraints, and replace them by `[String]`, this will give the same performance boost, regardless if the `print` statement is present or not.

```swift
class MyInterface {
    
    private let algorithm: Algorithm
    
    init(x: [String], y: [String]) {
    // ...
}

class Algorithm {
    
    var x: [String]
    var y: [String]
    
    init(x: [String], y: [String]) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
    
    func myrun() {
    }
}

class AlgorithmSubclass: Algorithm {
    
    override func myrun() {
    // ...
}
```

---

I don't know why that print statement prevents the optimal inlining, theoretically it should not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I would be really interested in is why that single statement prevents inlining. After all, there should be no dynamic dispatch as the `List` type is known at compile-time.

Comment: @Nickkk I'm not sure why the inlining fails with that extra `print`, maybe someone with more expertise on the clang inner works might give us a clue of why that happens. However please note that the dynamic dispatch still happens if there's no inlining, even if the types are known at compile time, as without inlining it would be just too much for the compiler to try and statically resolve all call paths.